# Why pack() is not resizing both ways (size up and shrink) - Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have a GUI with a JFrame with a JPanel that is being switched with a CardLayout manager. The code is this one:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class VistaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Stack<String> nomVistes;

    /**
     * Creates new form VistaPrincipal
     */
    public VistaPrincipal() {
        nomVistes = new Stack<>();

        initComponents();

        this.setTitle("Dynamic Academic Scheduler");
        this.setResizable(false);

    }

    public void tornarInici() {
        System.out.println("[ INFO ] Solicitat tornar al menu inicial");
       ((CardLayout) ventana.getLayout()).first(ventana);
       pack();
    } 

    public void tornarEnrere() {
       System.out.println("[ INFO ] Solicitat tornar a la vista anterior amb nom: " + nomVistes.peek());
       ((CardLayout) ventana.getLayout()).show(ventana, nomVistes.peek());
       pack();
       nomVistes.pop();
    }
```

These methods are the ones that really does the switching between JPanels.

```
       /**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    ventana = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

    ventana.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());
    getContentPane().add(ventana, "card2");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

initComponents() is automatically generated by Netbeans.

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JPanel ventana;
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

This is the JPanel where we visualize the rest of JPanels we are switching through.
    }

These methods allows me to go through several JPanels I have made, the case is that I use **pack()** to avoid messing around with hardwired sizes (setSize, minimumSize, max...), at the start this works fine, the JPanels are packed the good way until I switch to a bigger JPanel than the other ones and at the time that I go backwards (through the cards), the JFrame sticks to the bigger size it took...

So, **pack()** is working to make bigger the panel and fit it, but not to fit smaller panels once the panel has already made bigger. Maybe I misunderstood what **pack()** does?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Note that the way a `CardLayout` is typically used involves adding **all** the child components **at start-up**. The layout will then report the tallest height and widest width of all the components as the preferred size.

Comment: [pack()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) "Causes this Window to be sized to fit the **preferred size** and layouts of its subcomponents."  You need to set it for 'pack()` to be effective.

Comment: @c0der *"You need to set it for 'pack()` to be effective."* Huh? if 'it' is the preferred size, I've not had to do that except with custom components, occasionally the view port of a scroll pane, and .. not much else at all.

Comment: It really didn't helped me, maybe is an answer but it didn't work for me. I am not able to post a MCVE for a complete project... Sorry if I bothered you but I think is not that easy to make MCVE or even to test alone a single view. Sorry.

Comment: You are not expected to post [mcve] of the project but of the problem. An mcve is not meant to represent your project. It is meant to represent the problem.

Comment: So is this question answered? As far as I can tell, Andrew gave you the answer in his original comment. You should respond stating either the suggestion helped, or post your "MCVE". People don't want to spend time reading questions that have already been answered.

Comment: I finally tried the suggestion of Andrew and worked out, but how you usually add all the cards you want? Maybe some of them are generated dynamically, no? (How can I mark a comment as solution? xD)

Comment: Tip: Add @c0der (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"(How can I mark a comment as solution? xD)"* That's not possible. Options are: 1) Delete the question using link below the tags. 2) Write an answer yourself, showing the solution. 3) Encourage one of the commenters to upgrade their comment to an answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you. The comment that helped out was yours, so I heavily encourage you to write it as an answer. Otherwise sooner or later I will post it.